# What is the maximum amount of gold you can store in your wallet?

Tags: guild-wars-2

In the first Guild Wars, the Vault box could store up to 1000 platinum, and we were able to store 100 platinum on each characters. But what is the maximum amount of money you can get in your wallet in Guild Wars 2, imagining someone could one day reach this maximum if it exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is indeed a maximum to the amount of gold you can have in your wallet. This amount is 200,000 gold. It has been reached on January 3rd, 2017 by the Reddit user numerix, as he presented it himself in [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Guildwars2/comments/5luo6h/200000g_i_reached_the_maximum_of_gold_you_can/), and as we can see on [this picture](http://www.directupload.net/file/d/4590/nhjp7pez_jpg.htm).

If you are supposed to receive money from any other service, like the Trading Post, you won't receive it until you get enough place in your inventory to receive the **whole** amount of gold:

> I cant receive any more gold. If I go to the TP I only get the stuff I bought, but not the gold. It stay there until I put enought gold into the guild bank. If I have 199,999g and at the TP are 2g waiting for me, I get nothing, until I put one more gold into the bank.